# Bash - Regex Expression

Tags: bash

I want to parse out current folder color for papirus folders theme. I have the following string:

```
List of available colors: black blue bluegrey brown cyan deeporange green grey > indigo magenta nordic orange pink red teal violet white yellow
```

I have no experience with regex. I want to color after the `>` i.e. `indigo`. The color can vary.
Can anyone please help me with the regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a regex, a parameter expansion can do that just fine:

```
#!/bin/bash
string='List of available colors: black blue bluegrey brown cyan deeporange green grey > indigo magenta nordic orange pink red teal violet white yellow'

color=${string#*> }  # Remove everything up to "> ".
echo ${color%% *}    # Remove everything after the first space.
```